# Avoiding code duplication in Delphi

Tags: delphi, components, dry, code-duplication

I have two components A and B. Component B derives from component A and shares most properties and procedures with it. Now I have a lengthy procedure like this:

```
procedure DoSomething;
begin
  Form1.Caption := Component_A.Caption;
  // hundreds of additional lines of code calling component A
end;
```

Depending on whether component B is active or not, I would like to reuse the above procedure and replace the Component_A part with the name of component B. It should look like this then:

```
procedure DoSomething;
var
  C: TheComponentThatIsActive;
begin
  if Component_A.Active then
    C := Component_A;
  if Component_B.Active then
    C := Component_B;
  Form1.Caption := C.Caption;
end;
```

How can I do that in Delphi2007?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`TheComponentThatIsActive` should be the same type that `ComponentA` is (`TComponentA`).

Now, if you run into a stumbling block where some properties/methods only belong to `ComponentB`, then check and typecast it.

```
procedure DoSomething;
var
    C: TComponentA;

begin
    if Component_A.Active then
        C := Component_A
    else if Component_B.Active then
        C := Component_B
    else
        raise EShouldNotReachHere.Create();

    Form1.Caption := C.Caption;

    if C=Component_B then
        Component_B.B_Only_Method;
end;
```

Comment: you need to handle the case when neither is active or at leapt assert it can't happen. Also why use `is` when you can test `=Component_B`?

Comment: @David: Good catch on making sure that C gets assigned.  As for typecasting vs. direct calls, that depends on how many different components and types there are.  If we added a `Component_D` that's also of type `TComponentB`, or added a `TComponentX` into the mix that was a descendant of `TComponentB`, then there's less code to change my way, and it's simple enough to account for in advance.

Comment: In this example C=Component_B is equivalent to the is test though isn't it? I generally shy away from using `is` if possible.

Comment: @David: In this simplified test, yes.  In the actual program, only the OP knows and that will be a factor in deciding which solution is better.  It's possible that some refactoring may be in order for the OP, depending on what he or she needs to do with the code.

Comment: Do feel free to change it back. But leave the `raise` in obviously.  :-)

Comment: Thanks everyone. Appreciate it.

Answer (score 2):

You can  pass ComponentA or ComponentB to DoSomething as a parameter.

```
ComponentA = class
public 
 procedure Fuu();
 procedure Aqq();
end;

ComponentB = class(ComponentA)
public 
 procedure Blee();
end;

implementation

procedure DoSomething(context:ComponentA);
begin
  context.Fuu();
  context.Aqq();
end;

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var cA:ComponentA;
    cB:ComponentB;
begin
  cA:= ComponentA.Create();
  cB:= ComponentB.Create();

  DoSomething(cA);
  DoSomething(cB);

  cA.Free;
  cB.Free;
end;
```